# Twilio call diverting call to personal cellphone answering machine instead of twimlet

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml, twimlet

I am trying to use twimlbin code to forward calls to the voicemail box for my current twilio number.  The goal is to have a call come in, then it is split to call multiple numbers at the same time.  If none of the numbers pick up, then forwards it to voicemail where it is emailed to an email address using a twimlet link.  Currently this is my setup:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
<Dial action="https://twimlets.com/forward?FailUrl=https%3A%2F%2Ftwimlets.com%2Fvoicemail%3FEmail%myemail%2540gmail.com%26Message%3DSorry%2520we%2520are%2520unavailable%252C%2520please%2520leave%2520a%2520voicemail%2520here%2520and%2520let%2520us%2520know%2520what%2520you%2520need%2520and%2520we%2520will%2520get%2520back%2520to%2520you%2520shortly%252C%2520thank%2520you.%26Transcribe%3Dtrue&amp;Dial=true" record="record-from-answer" callerId="+13151234567">
    <Number url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8253d4550bfdaf385b2b2ac15e0a4392">3155554444</Number>
    <Number url="https://handler.twilio.com/twiml/EH8253d4550bfdaf385b2b2ac15e0a4392">7165554444</Number>
</Dial>
</Response>
```

Currently it routes the numbers properly and the phones receive the call, but when no one picks up, it just goes to the voicemail on the personal phones of the numbers where the call is being forwarded to.  Is there a way I can get the twimlet to work with this style of routing in Twilio?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog.

Outsmart Voice Mail with Human Detection Using Keypress Prompts

https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-mail-human-detection-studio-functions